# XDEBUG installation reading wrong PHP version

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, xdebug

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 vagrant box running on php 7.1.  When I try to build xdebug by running ./configure in xdebug-2.6.0 I get

```
Check for supported PHP versions... configure: error: not supported. Need a PHP version >= 7.0.0 and < 7.3.0 (found 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.24)
```

PHP -v yields

```
Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 320170718.
The Zend Engine API version 320160303 which is installed, is outdated.

PHP 7.1.15-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+2 (cli) (built: Mar  6 2018 11:27:08) ( NTS )
```

So the system is running 7.1, but for some reason the configure script thinks we're still on 5.5.9

I've hit google pretty hard, but  still can't find a way to update the Zend engine either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Most likely you have _two_ versions of php installed.

Comment: I did have several versions installed, but thought the script would default to the version returned by php --version.  I got the system working apt-get purging all the php5 packages.

Comment: Well no, how that. That obviously depends on what version you call when you use the command line command `php`. That depends on your installation and your `PATH` environment variable. The utilities cannot magically _guess_ what version you expect...

Answer (score 9):

It happens because you're configuring with default settings and that is different from the PHP version you're trying to configure.

Just like you saw the PHP version using the `php -v` command, check the php-config version using the `php-config --version` command, it should be the same as php -v, but in your case, it would be different and hence this issue.

Now let's talk about how we can solve it. Since you need a different version of config, you should point that to the configure command.

For example, in your case, you need php-config7.1 (because you're using PHP v7.1, similarly for 7.2 you have php-config7.2 and so on)

To point the configure command to a specific PHP version you need to specify that as a flag called with-php-config and the value should be the location of the php-config file, a sample would be

```
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config7.1
```

Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: **php-config** gets installed with **php7.1-dev** `sudo apt-get install php7.1-dev`

Comment: although the answer is correct in the end, @maqduni 's comment is the secret ingredient that makes the solution possible

Answer (score 2):

I assume you run phpize before running ./configure. Instead you need to run phpize7.1 and then ./configure

if you don't have phpize7.1 installed you can install it via:

```
sudo apt install apt install php7.1-dev
```